# How to filter string based on the searchView input

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, searchview

I want to create suggestions for my searchView.

I have a listView and a Map that contains the entire contacts list. I created a custom adapter to populate the ListView. I also have a searchView to allow user to search for specific contact.

Now I'm using OnQueryTextChange, but I don't know how to create an other Map to pass it in the adapter in order to display only names typed by the user.

I'm stuck because I just want to add a contact name based on the first letter. Example: If the user types "m" then I want to create a Map with all contact starting with "m", then the user continues adding letter and the Map should filter the contact until there is only one name.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            for (String name : mKeys) { // here Im looping the keys of my contact Map
                if (something) {
                   Map.put(name, contact.get(name));  // contact is the contact Map
                }
                createContactAdapter(Map);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Thanks for the help

**EDIT**

My updated code:

```
@Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Toast.makeText(ContactsActivity.this, newText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for (String name : mKeys) {
                name = name.trim();
                if (name.startsWith(newText) && newText.length() > 0)  {
                    mFilteredMap.put(name, "00000000000"); // NPE here

                    if (mFilteredMap.size() > 1) {
                        createContactAdapter(mFilteredMap);
                    }
                }


            } 
            return false;
```

first let's handle only the adding function.

Comment: What problems are facing with what you have?

Comment: the if condition needs to be replaced of course!

Comment: Of course? Not sure that's as obvious as you think. If you don't have an if don't you just populate the list with all the key/values?

Comment: I mean: if (something) <- this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it now. Is...

`if (name.startsWith(newText))`

what you're looking for?

[String.startsWith()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))

This would see if the key begins with the text from the search; if so, add it to the map.

At this point you'd have a map of *all* keys for the first letter. If you want to filter this map you'll have to have an `empty` check to see which set of keys you're working on. Then you'd have to remove all entries with...

`if (! name.startsWith(newText)) { /* remove it */ }`

This tells you that the given key *doesn't* match the search and then you remove it.

Comment: @Agostinellli - helpful at all?

Comment: Yes, you helped a lot, but I still have some problem. I have a NPE.

How can I post other code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use this map, create another map call it filteredMap, and every time the user type something, you clear the filteredMap, Iterate over the original map, and move the items that contains or start with the typed text,  create adapter with the filteredMap, 
Use thw startWith and contains to move the right items only, as mentioned above...

Comment: I think, or rather assumed, that OP was talking about a separate map. I thought that was implied by the post since they have a contact map and another. I also wouldn't, after I've created the already "stripped down map", continue to query the og. That could potentially, w/o proper care, be a significant waste of resources. You already have the sub-set of the keys you care about. That's certainly more efficient than continually checking for the ones you know already fit.